# How do I add multiple subtotals in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

My report has the following structure

ID , Currency, Subdepartment, Unit , Revenue, Salary

I wanted to print the subtotals of Revenue and Salary for the following combinations
(ID, Currency, Subdepartment)
(ID, Currency, )

The row has discrete dimensions hence the default grandtotal/subtotal option is not working .

is thr an alternate to calculate the subtotals and display beneath each grouping.?

Comment: I don't get it. Discrete dimensions should not mess with subtotals. Can you provide a .twbx or a screenshot of what is happening?

Comment: Tableau is NOT EXCEL! It's very hard for people to remember this is a visualization tool. Easy things in excel are a hack or impossible to do in Tableau. To create a subtotal you're going to have to create a new calculated field and have a running subtotal.

Answer (score 0):

If you're hoping to see this in a single worksheet, it sounds like a job for [LOD (level-of-detail) functions](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/v9.0/pro/online/windows/en-us/help.html#calculations_calculatedfields_lod.html). I'm not sure how you want to visualize it, but here's how you could simply make a table.

Create some calculated fields:

1. Revenue Total (ID, Currency)

   ```
   { FIXED [Id], [Currency] : SUM([Revenue]) }
   ```
2. Salary Total (ID, Currency)

   ```
   { FIXED [Id], [Currency] : SUM([Salary]) }
   ```

We can then create a table (for example) with the subtotals and totals by placing the following pills in the Rows shelf, in this order:

1. `[ID]`
2. `[Currency]`
3. `SUM([Revenue Total (ID, Currency)])` (Make it discrete)
4. `SUM([Salary Total (ID, Currency)])` (Make it discrete)
5. `[Subdepartment]`
6. `SUM([Revenue])` (Make it discrete)
7. `SUM([Salary])` (Make it discrete)

The resulting table will look something like this:

```
 ID   Currency   Total Revenue   Total Salary   Subdepartment   Revenue   Salary
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 A    Dollars    $200            $100           R               $140      $30
                                                S               $60       $70
      Manat      ₼4000           ₼8000          R               ₼1000     ₼7000
                                                S               ₼3000     ₼1000
      Yen        ¥500            ¥1000          R               ¥100      ¥300
                                                S               ¥200      ¥500          
                                                T               ¥200      ¥200
 B    Dollars    $300            $700           R               $200      $600
                                                S               $100      $100
      Manat      ₼7000           ₼3000          R               ₼2000     ₼1000
                                                S               ₼3000     ₼1000
                                                T               ₼2000     ₼1000
      Yen        ¥900            ¥400           R               ¥150      ¥100
                                                S               ¥250      ¥100          
                                                T               ¥300      ¥200
```

---

All that said, FirebladeDan makes a great point in the comments of your question. Tableau is NOT Excel – it's a visualization tool, and a smokin' one at that. If you want to show aggregations of measures at different levels of detail, your best option (both in terms of what Tableau can easily do and the clearest way to visualize it) is usually going to be to create a dashboard with multiple worksheets at different levels of detail and to take advantage of filter actions and other controls to see how it all relates.